# Railsapp OAuth Tutorial, rspec "unitialized constant" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, oauth, railsapps

Following the tutorial, I created a file omniauth.rb at the path

**spec/support/helpers/omniauth.rb**

```
module Omniauth

  module Mock
    def auth_mock
      OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {
        'provider' => 'twitter',
        'uid' => '123545',
        'user_info' => {
          'name' => 'mockuser'
        },
        'credentials' => {
          'token' => 'mock_token',
          'secret' => 'mock_secret'
        }
      }
    end
  end

end
```

But when I run rspec, I get an error with "uninitialized constant Omniauth"

```
rails-omniauth/spec/support/helpers.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Omniauth (NameError)
```

It seems clear that either omniauth.rb or helpers.rb should be in a different location, but I don't know where.

**Update**:

I subsequently tried installing the rails-omniauth via the Rails Composer app. When I run "rspec" for this app, I get exactly the same error.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232281/how-to-get-rid-of-uninitialized-constant-omniauth-nameerror.  YMMV.

Comment: I know it seems vague but the tutorials are actually called "Railsapps". The website is here: https://tutorials.railsapps.org/

Answer (score 0):

At one point in the tutorial you are given a choice between creating a file at at `/spec/support/helpers.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Omniauth::Mock
  config.include Omniauth::SessionHelpers, type: :feature
end
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

Or adding these same lines to `/spec/rails_helper.rb`.

I created the new file at `/spec/support/helpers.rb`. To make this work, I needed to add the line `require_relative 'helpers/omniauth'` at the top of the file.  The Rails Composer app also adds the `helpers.rb` file rather than editing `rails_helper.rb`, so the same line is needed to make rspec run successfully for that app.